# does MySQL BLOB only accept images?

Tags: php, mysql

Does MySQL BLOB only accept images?

I have been looking online trying to be able to upload larger file sizes of different formats, but I only come across image tutorials.

I have the code below, which fails on the `if` statement and returns the `echo` when I upload different file types larger than 10 megs. (the column is `LONGBLOB`).

```
<?php
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');  //On or Off

 session_start();
 require_once('connect.php');

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
         $file = rand(1000,100000)."-".$_FILES['file']['name'];
         $notes = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['notes']);
         $file_loc = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
         $file_size = $_FILES['file']['size'];
         $file_type = $_FILES['file']['type'];

         $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_SESSION['email']);
         $folder="uploads/";

          move_uploaded_file($file_loc,$folder.$file);

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `supportcontent` (`scontentdata`, `scontentnotes`, `suseremail`, `stype`,`ssize`)
            VALUES( '$file','$notes','$email','$file_type ','$file_size')";

            $current_id = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) 
            or die("<b>Error:</b> Problem on Image Insert<br/>" . mysqli_error($connection));
            if (isset($current_id)) {
                header("Location: landingpage.php?upload=success");
            }
        }
        else{       
            echo 'file is 0';
        }   
?>
```

Comment: *Does MySQL BLOB only accept images?*, no, it doesn't care what you store in it, so you can store anything you want. What's failing when you try to upload a file over 10MB is not the SQL, but the PHP code. Either the files size limit or the operation timing out.

Comment: No. Anything can be a blob. But note that it's generally considered poor practice to store larger files in the db, because a dedicated file server is so much better at handling them than the db.

Comment: "A BLOB is a binary large object that can hold a variable amount of data. " any binary data

Comment: From MySQL documentation : " A BLOB is a binary large object that can hold a variable amount of data. The four BLOB types are TINYBLOB, BLOB, MEDIUMBLOB, and LONGBLOB. These differ only in the maximum length of the values they can hold." 

Make sure you are using the right datatype in your table schema. Also check if your max_allowed_packet is set to greater than 10MB

Comment: I would ask why you need BLOB in the firs place? From the code provided I can see that you only put string/numeric data about uploaded file into the DB, not the actual content of the file. The only instruction regarding actual content of the file is moving it from temporary location to permanent one. Also I would point that you should not use $_FILES['file']['name'] to create new file name, see the example on [Handling file uploads page](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php). esp. example how to obtain safe unique name for a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does MySQL BLOB only accept images?

No, you can store anything you want in it. What's failing when you try to upload a file over 10MB is not the SQL, but the PHP code. Either:

1. the files size limit. Check the value of the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` settings in the php.ini file.
2. or the operation timing out. This is more likely to be the culprit especially if you've never changed the default values in your php.ini file. The default timeout in PHP is 30 seconds, so your file must be uploaded in less than 30 seconds. You can change it in the php.ini file using the `max_execution_time` setting, or it is better to change it in you code using the `set_time_limit()` function.

Example, to set the timeout to 2 minutes:

```
set_time_limit(120);
```

Comment: thank you, this seems to have helped and allows bigger files to be uploaded. though  think it keeps timing out depending on the size of the file.

Comment: You can set it to more than 2 minutes if you like (or set it to zero `set_time_limit(0)` for no limit, but this is not recommended). Remember to provide some progress or animation for the user to know that it is still uploading.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the value of max_allowed_packet size and check if this is set to greater than 10MB to handle your case.